# Java script code Not working

Tags: javascript

In this code During lioading Only part 1 is display.
 when Click on  more  then part of html code display
But following Java script Is not working . If any one have solution pls answer.

```
     <div class="box">
 <h2 > west delhi</h2>
 <span class=" first-paragraph teaser ">Part 1 </span>
 <span class="toggle" style="display: none;">  Part 2</span>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="moreBtn" style="color:#ff0000;">more...</a>
</div> 






<script src="js/return_city_name.js"> document.readyState()</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js">   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".box .moreBtn").click(function () {
                $(this).parent('.box').find(".toggle").toggle(); 
                if($(this).parent('.box').find('.toggle').css('display')=='none'){
                    $(this).text('more');
                }else{
                    $(this).text('less');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery to your code.

Download (http://jquery.com/download/) and reference it in your HTML head section:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Or use one of the CDNs:

Google:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Microsoft:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box .moreBtn").click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.box').find(".toggle").toggle();
    if ($(this).parent('.box').find('.toggle').css('display') == 'none') {
      $(this).text('more');
    } else {
      $(this).text('less');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <h2> west delhi</h2>
  <span class=" first-paragraph teaser ">Part 1 </span>
  <span class="toggle" style="display: none;">  Part 2</span>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="moreBtn" style="color:#ff0000;">more...</a>
</div>
```

Is it what you want? or need something else?